# PopOs 20.04 Wifi drivers failed to load

Tags: network-interface, iwlwifi

Everything was working fine, when I start my laptop today, wifi section was missing and I could connect only from wired connection. But wifi is still missing.

Im new to linux, if anything Im doing wrong please help.

```
$ lspci | grep Network
3d:00.0 Network controller: **Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)**

$ dhclient wlan0
Cannot find device "wlan0"

$ cd Downloads
$ cd iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0
$ ls
iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode    README.iwlwifi-cc.ucode
LICENSE.iwlwifi-cc.ucode
$ sudo cp iwlwifi* /lib/firmware
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    4.589179] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.063474] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:3d:00.0 failed with error -110
```

And its weird it works on somedays.

Comment: Hi, is it dual boot with windows?

Comment: Yes. @binarysta

Comment: Please have a look at my answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593848/254422

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WiFi not working Kubuntu 20.04 - Intel 8265 Network Interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593826/wifi-not-working-kubuntu-20-04-intel-8265-network-interface)

Comment: @binarysta it works (ʘᴗʘ✿) thanks