# WiFi hard blocked after updating BIOS on HP laptop

Tags: debian, wifi, bios

I have dual boot Windows and Debian on my HP laptop. Since I updated by BIOS from `F.18` to `F.45` my wifi has been hard blocked on Debian but it works fine on Windows.

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

I have tried toggling physical wifi switch OFF/ON but nothing happens. Tried unloading `hp_wmi` and `hp_wireless` then toggling physical wifi switch OFF/ON but still no luck.

Ouput of `lshw` for wireless network

```
           *-network DISABLED
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
                vendor: Ralink corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
                logical name: wlp10s0f0
                version: 00
                serial: fa:ba:fe:01:ad:24
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.19.0-13-amd64 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Output of [dmesg](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4JYSZZH3k9/).

Output of `dmesg | grep rt28`

```
[   16.820913] rt2800pci 0000:0a:00.0 wlp10s0f0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: you better post the output of `dmesg` for your wifi and please have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593826/wifi-not-working-kubuntu-20-04-intel-8265-network-interface/593848#593848

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: please provide `dmesg | grep rt28`

Comment: @binarysta I have check my dmesg output. I didn't find anything in it related to my WiFi drivers. Even for Live Ubuntu USB the wifi hardware was disabled. But WiFi works perfectly on windows. Somethings up with windows I suspect

Comment: Do you have the `firmware-misc-nonfree` package installed on your Debian? Often errors like this are caused by a missing WiFi firmware file.

Comment: Yes I have installed it. Generally if such firmwares are missing `dmesg` suggests something. But this time it does not help.

Comment: could you do `ip link set wlp10s0f0 up` while in another terminal tailing dmesg `dmesg | tail -f` ? maybe we see some useful errors

Comment: `dmesg | tail -f` didn't work as expected. It didn't wait for `dmesg` to be modified, instead it just printed and existed. I think `-f` flag does not work when input is piped.

Comment: @AkashKarnatak yes, it was my mistake, please run `dmesg -w` and then try `ip link set wlp10s0f0 up`.

Comment: `dmesg` did not update and `ip link set wlp10s0f0 up` prints `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill`

Comment: Please, try to "unlock" WiFi by the WiFi button using combination even Fn+WiFi, or on the some notebooks there is special button to switch WiFi on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem,

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2457745

According to [this](https://gsid.in/using-old-mini-pcie-wlan-cards-in-modern-laptops) page,

> Older generation of WiFi mini PCI-E cards from a while ago usually
> have a hardware kill switch. This RF kill switch was usually connected
> to one of the pins on the Mini PCI-E header. Modern laptops are unable
> to turn on the WLAN card. Modern laptops can read and initialize the
> PCI-E card, but the radio part of the card is turned off.
>
> From reading up on the spec sheet of several WLAN Mini-PCIE card from
> 7 years ago i found that that Mini-PCIE pin 20 which according to the
> specs was reserved for vendor specific purposes was being utilized as
> a RF kill switch.Similarly in cards with WiFi and Bluetooth, pin 51 is
> set for Bluetooth disable along with the pin 20 for WLAN disable.

Therefore, you just have to tape pin 20 on your wireless card. The pins are labeled alternately. Odd numbered pins are on the front side and even numbered pins on the back side.

Front view,

[image]

Back view,

[image]

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzAKcmlaH1M) video if you still don't understand.

I used cello tape to mask pin 20, although use of electrical tape is recommended.

[image]